# How do I deal with "signed/unsigned mismatch" warnings (C4018)?

Tags: c++, comparison, refactoring, unsigned, signed

I work with a lot of calculation code written in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) with high-performance and low memory overhead in mind. It uses STL containers (mostly `std::vector`) a lot, and iterates over that containers almost in every single function.

The iterating code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); ++i)
{
    // ...
}
```

But it produces the **signed/unsigned mismatch** warning (**C4018 in Visual Studio**).

Replacing `int` with some `unsigned` type is a problem because we frequently use `OpenMP` pragmas, and it requires the counter to be `int`.

I'm about to suppress the (hundreds of) warnings, but I'm afraid I've missed some elegant solution to the problem.

**On iterators**. I think iterators are great when applied in appropriate places. The code I'm working with will *never* change random-access containers into `std::list` or something (so iterating with `int i` is already container agnostic), and will *always* need the current index. And all the additional code you need to type (iterator itself and the index) just complicates matters and obfuscates the simplicity of the underlying code.

Comment: Can you post an example where the OpenMP pragma prevents you using an unsigned type? According to [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Fruprpdir.htm) it should work for any intergal type, not just `int`.

Comment: I believe this question is better for stackoverflow.

Comment: `int` and `std::vector<T>::size_type` may also be different in size as well as in signedness.  For example, on a LLP64 system (like 64-bit Windows), `sizeof(int) == 4` but `sizeof(std::vector<T>::size_type) == 8`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [acceptable fix for majority of signed/unsigned warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275853/acceptable-fix-for-majority-of-signed-unsigned-warnings)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188401/c-warning-c4018-signed-unsigned-mismatch

Comment: Check this suggestion https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/33336253-do-not-show-warning-on-a-mixed-comparison-where-on

Answer (score 71):

It's all in your `things.size()` type. It isn't `int`, but `size_t` (it exists in C++, not in C) which equals to some "usual" unsigned type, i.e. `unsigned int` for x86_32.

Operator "less" (<) cannot be applied to two operands of different sign. There's just no such opcodes, and standard doesn't specify, whether compiler can make implicit sign conversion. So it just treats signed number as unsigned and emits that warning.

It would be correct to write it like

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < things.size(); ++i) { /**/ }
```

or even faster

```
for (size_t i = 0, ilen = things.size(); i < ilen; ++i) { /**/ }
```

Comment: -1 no, it is not `size_t`. Its is `std::vector< THING >::size_type`.

Comment: @Raedwald:  While you're technically correct, it's hard to imagine how a standards-compliant implementation could end up with different underlying types for `std::size_t` and `std::vector<T>::size_type`.

Comment: why is ++i being considered better? In for loops isn't there "no" difference?

Comment: @ShoaibHaider, it doesn't matter at all for primitives where the return value isn't being used. However, for *custom types* (where the operator is overloaded), post increment is almost always less efficient (since it has to make a copy of the object before it was incremented). Compilers can't (necessarily) optimize for custom types. So the only advantage is consistency (of primitives vs custom types).

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy `std::vector<T>::size_type` depends on the allocator used. If the default allocator (`std::allocator<T>`) is used, then `size_type == std::size_t`. For custom allocators, `size_type` might be something else than `std::size_t`.

Comment: @zenith:  Yes, you're right.  My statement holds only for the default allocator.  A custom allocator might use something other than std::size_t, but I believe it would still have to be an unsigned integral type, and it probably couldn't represent a larger range than std::size_t, so it's still safe to use std::size_t as the type for a loop index.

Comment: I'm unclear what is meant by this part of the answer: "standard doesn't specify[...] whether compiler can make implicit sign conversion."  The standard requires the conversion ("[I]f the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.")

Comment: @TREMOR, `++i` is generally considered better because `i++` is typically implemented in terms of `++i`. This means that by using `++i` you avoid one additional function call and get slightly better performance (although it is negligible in most cases)

Answer (score 13):

Ideally, I would use a construct like this instead:

```
for (std::vector<your_type>::const_iterator i = things.begin(); i != things.end(); ++i)
{
  // if you ever need the distance, you may call std::distance
  // it won't cause any overhead because the compiler will likely optimize the call
  size_t distance = std::distance(things.begin(), i);
}
```

This a has the neat advantage that your code suddenly becomes container agnostic.

And regarding your problem, if some library you use requires you to use `int` where an `unsigned int` would better fit, their API is messy. Anyway, if you are sure that those `int` are always positive, you may just do:

```
int int_distance = static_cast<int>(distance);
```

Which will specify clearly your intent to the compiler: it won't bug you with warnings anymore.

Comment: I _always_ need the distance. Maybe `static_cast<int>(things.size())` could be the solutions, if there are no others.

Comment: @Andrew: If you do decide to suppress the warning, the best way would probably be to use a compiler specific pragma (on MSVC this will be a `#pragma warning(push) #pragma warning(disable: 4018) /* ... function  */ #pragma warning(pop)`) rather than to use a needless cast. (Casts hide legitimate errors, m'kay? ;) )

Comment: Not true. Cast != conversion. The warning is warning about an implicit conversion allowed by the standard which may be unsafe. A cast, however, invites explicit conversions to the party which can be more unsafe than what was originally talked about by the warning. Strictly speaking, at least on x86, no conversion is going to happen at all -- the processor does not care whether you are treating a specific part of memory as signed or unsigned, so long as you use the correct instructions to work with it.

Comment: When being container-agnostic causes O(N^2) complexity (and in your example it does, as distance() is O(N) for list<>), I am not so sure it is an advantage :-(.

Comment: @No-BugsHare That's exactly the point: we can't be sure. If the OP has few elements, then it's probably great. If he has millions of those, probably not so much. Only profiling can tell in the end but the good news is: you can always optimize maintainable code!

Answer (score 11):

If you can't/won't use iterators and if you can't/won't use `std::size_t` for the loop index, make a `.size()` to `int` conversion function that documents the assumption and does the conversion explicitly to silence the compiler warning.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <limits>

// When using int loop indexes, use size_as_int(container) instead of
// container.size() in order to document the inherent assumption that the size
// of the container can be represented by an int.
template <typename ContainerType>
/* constexpr */ int size_as_int(const ContainerType &c) {
    const auto size = c.size();  // if no auto, use `typename ContainerType::size_type`
    assert(size <= static_cast<std::size_t>(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()));
    return static_cast<int>(size);
}
```

Then you write your loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size_as_int(things); ++i) { ... }
```

The instantiation of this function template will almost certainly be inlined.  In debug builds, the assumption will be checked. In release builds, it won't be and the code will be as fast as if you called size() directly.  Neither version will produce a compiler warning, and it's only a slight modification to the idiomatic loop.

If you want to catch assumption failures in the release version as well, you can replace the assertion with an if statement that throws something like `std::out_of_range("container size exceeds range of int")`.

Note that this solves both the signed/unsigned comparison as well as the potential `sizeof(int)` != `sizeof(Container::size_type)` problem.  You can leave all your warnings enabled and use them to catch real bugs in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 7):

### C++20 has now [`std::cmp_less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp)

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), we have the standard  `constexpr` functions

```
std::cmp_equal
std::cmp_not_equal
std::cmp_less
std::cmp_greater
std::cmp_less_equal
std::cmp_greater_equal
```

added in the [`<utility>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/utility) header, exactly for this kind of scenarios.

> Compare the values of two integers `t` and `u`. Unlike builtin comparison operators, negative signed integers always compare less than (and not equal to) unsigned integers: **the comparison is safe against lossy integer conversion**.

That means, if (due to some wired reasons) one must use the `i` as `int`eger, the loops, and needs to compare with the unsigned integer, that can be done:

```
#include <utility> // std::cmp_less

for (int i = 0; std::cmp_less(i, things.size()); ++i)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

This also covers the case, if we mistakenly `static_cast` the `-1` (i.e. `int`)to `unsigned int`. That means, the following will not give you an error:

```
static_assert(1u < -1);
```

But the usage of `std::cmp_less` will

```
static_assert(std::cmp_less(1u, -1)); // error
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

1. size_t type, to remove warning messages
2. iterators + distance (like are first hint)
3. only iterators
4. function object

For example:

```
// simple class who output his value
class ConsoleOutput
{
public:
  ConsoleOutput(int value):m_value(value) { }
  int Value() const { return m_value; }
private:
  int m_value;
};

// functional object
class Predicat
{
public:
  void operator()(ConsoleOutput const& item)
  {
    std::cout << item.Value() << std::endl;
  }
};

void main()
{
  // fill list
  std::vector<ConsoleOutput> list;
  list.push_back(ConsoleOutput(1));
  list.push_back(ConsoleOutput(8));

  // 1) using size_t
  for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << list.at(i).Value() << std::endl;
  }

  // 2) iterators + distance, for std::distance only non const iterators
  std::vector<ConsoleOutput>::iterator itDistance = list.begin(), endDistance = list.end();
  for ( ; itDistance != endDistance; ++itDistance)
  {
    // int or size_t
    int const position = static_cast<int>(std::distance(list.begin(), itDistance));
    std::cout << list.at(position).Value() << std::endl;
  }

  // 3) iterators
  std::vector<ConsoleOutput>::const_iterator it = list.begin(), end = list.end();
  for ( ; it != end; ++it)
  {
    std::cout << (*it).Value() << std::endl;
  }
  // 4) functional objects
  std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), Predicat());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can also propose following solution for C++11.

```
for (auto p = 0U; p < sys.size(); p++) {

}
```

(C++ is not smart enough for auto p = 0, so I have to put p = 0U....)

Comment: +1 for C++11. Unless there is a *good* reason you can't use C++11, I think it's best to use the new features... they are meant to be a great help. And definitely use `for (auto thing : vector_of_things)` if you don't actually need the index.

Comment: But that solves only the signedness problem.  It doesn't help if `size()` returns a type larger than unsigned int, which is extremely common.

Answer (score 4):

I will give you a better idea

```
for(decltype(things.size()) i = 0; i < things.size(); i++){
                   //...
}
```

`decltype` is

> Inspects the declared type of an entity or the type and value category
>   of an expression.

So, It deduces type of `things.size()` and `i` will be a type as same as `things.size()`. So, 
`i < things.size()` will be executed without any warning

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Using size_t was not working. I tried the other one which worked for me. (as below)

```
for(int i = things.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
{
 //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do

```
int pnSize = primeNumber.size();
for (int i = 0; i < pnSize; i++)
    cout << primeNumber[i] << ' ';
```