# C++ warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch

Tags: c++, warnings

This code throws a warnings when I compile it under windows. Any solutions?

```
#include<vector> 

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v;
  //...
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { //warning on this line
    //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Replace all the definitions of `int i` with `size_t i`.

`std::vector<T>::size()` returns the type `size_t` which is unsigned (since it doesn't make sense for containers to contain a negative number of elements).

Comment: This is bad idea since -3 int would be bigger then size_t 31 with your solution. While this solution works for current example, this may lead to hard to debug bugs in other cases.

Answer (score 8):

Say `std::size_t i = 0;`:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also use iterators instead to avoid the potential for a warning altogether:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
{
    ...
}
```

Or if you're using C++11:

```
for (int i : v)
{
    ...
}
```