# C++ Process terminated with status -1073741819

Tags: c++, c++11

I am creating a little dictionary.I have created a vector of strings to print some words beforehand to take one of those as input from user and describing the word to them.

I have tried googling about it and tried to set `unsigned int i = 0` in the for loop.

The part of the code that does so is given below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> word = {"none", "jump fatigue" , "scrim game", "box up", "turtling", "swing", "flickshot", "tracking", "panic build", "cone jump", "ttv", "one-shot", "tagged", "blue", "white", "lasered", "melted", "default", "bot", "stealth", "aggresive", "sweaty", "tryhard", "choke"};
    for(int i = 0; i <= word.size(); i++){
        cout<<i<<")"<< word[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prints without any error and at the end of running the code it freezes for while and ends with,
`Process terminated with status -1073741819(0 minute(s), 4 second(s))`
whereas it's supposed to terminate with 0

While debugging the code I get 
`warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]`

Comment: `i <=` should be `i <`, your last loop iteration reads past the end of the vector. Or even better, use a range-based for loop to avoid that kind of mistake.

Comment: ^^ Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443222/how-do-i-deal-with-signed-unsigned-mismatch-warnings-c4018

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your for loop `i <= word.size()`. This should be `<`. The last index will be one less than the size, since the first index is 0.

I'd recommend at least using `size_t` in the for loop to get a better type

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
```

though a cleaner way to iterate would be a range-based for loop

```
for (auto& w : word) {
    std::cout << w << '\n';
}
```